# API for getting spawned VMs ID?

Tags: java, api, jvm

While running a java application with the jvm. I would like to know how many instances of the VM are created,
and print the ID for each spawned VM

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there is a class (though not part of the public API),
`VMMmangementImpl`. The method `getVmId()` gives the id of the running VM.